# SMS and PHP... and Google Voice?

Tags: php, sms, google-voice

I've been searching for a few hours on the best way to add sms notifications and reception to my PHP website. It seems that it's easy to send texts (to an email forward to a phone), but hard to receive them without an SMS gateway. Clickatell was recommended a lot.

But: I stumbled across a few article recommending Google Voice as a channel to send and receive SMS. (Here's one post: http://sudocode.net/article/190/receiving-incoming-smstext-messages-from-google-voice-in-php/)

**Is there any reason I shouldn't/can't use a Google Voice number (and PHP) to handle my sms outbound and inbound messages?**

Comment: For anyone looking, the link is now http://codecri.me/case/190/receiving-incoming-smstext-messages-from-google-voice-in-php/

Answer (score 2):

I would check the Google Voice terms of service. If this is a commercial venture, I believe that's prohibited. Also since there is no official API, things could change at any time and break your app.

If you need reliable incoming or outgoing SMS there is no substitute for a gateway. I would recommend one, but I am not an impartial observer (see profile).

Answer (score 0):

There is no official PHP API for Google Voice, however I used [GVmax](http://www.gvmax.com) along with this [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/hawaiianchimp/gvmax-php-sdk) to create a website called [Memebro](http://memebro.com).