# Google Voice via OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-voice

My goal is to retrieve Google Voice voicemail audio messages and download them.

On May 27, 2015 - Google permanently disabled the ClientLogin API for Google Voice and encouraged migration to OAuth2.0.

I created a project in the Google Developers Console, but I was unable to identify the API that should be used.  I am not alone ([Google voice PHP OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471946/google-voice-php-oauth-2-0)).

It seems unlikely to me that Google would permanently disable the Google Voice ClientLogin API without having a working solution available -
especially since they deprecated the GV ClientLogin API more than 2 years ago and left it available for use for so long afterwards.

After further research, I discovered that the GMail API permits downloading of attachments.

Theoretically, if I set Google Voice to forward all Voicemails to GMail, I could download the audio file using the GMail API
(gmail.users.messages.attachments.get).

**NOTE:** I am not certain that this will work!  I worry it may not because when you click on *Play Message* in Gmail, it forwards to the Google Voice
page - where you can choose to download the message.  It seems this approach may result in needing a Google Voice API as well.

How are we supposed to retrieve Google Voice voicemail audio messages and download them using OAuth2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I own a Google Voice app for Windows 8 ([GVoice](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.microsoft.com%2Fwindows%2Fen-us%2Fapp%2Fgvoice%2Fb34a71c0-c183-432c-8780-64d0e2466a16&ei=_oqZVevZOoayyATG74KoCQ&usg=AFQjCNGsU--4pM1yCrt8bzlCrsWlv-hgyQ&sig2=_l2E9eosR3q5UqFtG7tU7A&bvm=bv.96952980,d.b2w)) which very recently broke due to the removal of ClientLogin. From my research it looks like there is now no longer a programmatic way to authenticate to Google Voice. ClientLogin is gone, and Google Voice is not a select-able API in Google's (OAuth) Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to interpret this question as "how do I programmatically access Google Voice now that the ClientLogin service is no longer available?"

My app uses the unofficial [google-voice-java API](https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/), and that API also broke in June 2015 when the ClientLogin service stopped working.

I was able to get it working again by having it log in using a different method, but not with OAuth 2.0. See the [comment thread for issue 60](https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/issues/detail?id=60) (see comments 6 and 9 in particular) for an outline of the solution.